# The magic rendering forms and variables through partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anyone please explain to me what's going on behind the scenes here

Going through a tutorial on creating a task-manager I needed to display my tasks, so I went with

```
each .. do
```

But then I needed to add some checkboxes and buttons to cross out my tasks and move them into another category, which means dealing with forms. After a few unsuccessful tries of merging do/each with form for I went online and I've stumbled upon this code:

index:

```
<%= render @incomplete_tasks %>
<%= render @completed_tasks %>
```

_task partial:

```
<%= form_for task do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :complete %>
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  <%= f.label :complete, task.name %>
  <%= link_to "(remove)", task, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
<% end %>
```

This renders out the needed code properly (WAT!), which is good, but I have no idea how does it do it, which is bad. Unfortunately, there is not much info on rendering variables in the docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

How does Rails know that I want to render _task partial for specific variable? Is this the naming convention in action?

How can I code in this form without partials?

Comment: Yes, it's naming. You could emit the form manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, naming convention is indeed in action.

If the variable passed is an Array-like object, it automatically sets up the `:collection` option for rendering partials. And for each element of the collection, it tries to render the partial of the same name as the ActiveRecord object in the collection.

Without partials, you can do:

```
<% @incomplete_tasks.each do |task| %>
  <%= form_for task do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box :complete %>
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
    <%= f.label :complete, task.name %>
    <%= link_to "(remove)", task, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```