# Rendering a partial using specific controller variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to play with Rails naming conventions as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832781/the-magic-rendering-forms-and-variables-through-partials) and render two different pages with different variables using one partial.

index

```
<%= render @events_future %>
```

current

```
<%= render @events_current %>
```

event controller

```
def index
  @events_future = ...
end
```

_event.html.erb

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
...
<% end %>
```

I get the undefined "each" method
Please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best thing to do here is to pass a `locals` to the partial `_event.html.erb` because the partial needs to display different objects like follows:

index

```
<%= render 'event', events: @events_future %>
```

current

```
<%= render 'event', events: @events_current %>
```

In the above two `render` statements, the `events` gets passed to the `event` partial as a local.

Then in your `_event.html.erb` you would do:

```
<% events.each do |event| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the variable to the partial when you render it:

```
render :partial => 'event', :locals => {:events => @events_current} %>
render :partial => 'event', :locals => {:events => @events_future} %>
```

And then in your partial you do:

```
<% events.each do |event| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Okay I delete my comment then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `@events` initialized in your controller?

I see that you have `@events_future` and `@events_current`, but if `@events` is not defined in the controller, your view wouldn't know what you are referring to.

If you want to reuse `events` for both future and current, use the following in each view

```
<!-- index.html.erb -->
<%= render 'event', events: @events_future %>

<!-- current.html.erb -->
<%= render 'event', events: @events_current %>
```

This renders the `_event.html.erb` partial and sets the `events` local variable. In `_event.html.erb`, use

```
<% events.each do |event| %>
  <!-- do stuff -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: No I do not have @events initialised, but  got it all working (see answer above)